# Update multiple checkboxes on association model through nested attributes | Cocoon gem | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I have a House model, which has_many `house_rules`

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :house_rules, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :house_rules, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is the house_rule model

```
class HouseRule < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :house
 enum rule_type: { predefined: 0, user_defined: 1 }
 enum allowed: { no: 0, yes: 1 }
end
```

Here are the other columns of `house_rules` table

```
create_table "house_rules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "house_id"
    t.string   "rule"
    t.integer  "rule_type",  default: 1
    t.integer  "allowed",    default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end
```

I have some predefined house_rules saved in database with `allowed` column set to `0` by default.For example:

```
<HouseRule id: 4, house_id: nil, rule: "Smoking allowed", rule_type: 0, allowed: 0, created_at: "2017-03-26 20:54:09", updated_at: "2017-03-26 20:54:09">
```

I want to have all these `house_rules` as check_boxes in the new `house` form. Like this.
[image]

So, when users checks the checkbox with label 'Smoking allowed', a new record is created like this

```
<HouseRule id: 5, house_id: 1, rule: "Smoking allowed", rule_type: 1, allowed: 1, created_at: "2017-03-26 20:54:09", updated_at: "2017-03-26 20:54:09">

rule_type: 1 #user_defined rule
allowed: 1   #smoking is allowed
```

This is my new `house` form

```
<%= simple_form_for @house do |f| %>
<div id="house_rules">
  <%=  f.simple_fields_for :house_rules do |house_rule| %>
  <% HouseRule.predefined.each do |rule| %>
  <div>
    <%= house_rule.label :allowed, rule.rule %>
    <%= house_rule.check_box :allowed, {}, 'yes', 'no' %> 
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The above code shows the checkboxes as expected, but doesn't work as expected. Can someone guide me on how to make this work?

Also, I have whitelisted these in HousesController

```
house_rules_attributes: [:id, :allowed, :_destroy])
```

---

## Edit:

This is the code the form produces for each checkbox

```
<label for="house_house_rules_attributes_0_allowed">Smoking Allowed</label>
 <input name="house[house_rules_attributes][0][allowed]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="house[house_rules_attributes][0][allowed]" id="house_house_rules_attributes_0_allowed">
```

The problem is, the `id` and `name` attributes are same for all the checkboxes, so even if I check a checkbox, only the first checkbox is always being checked.

A new house_rule record is being created for the associated house, but the `allowed` value is still `0`, it's not `1`.

This is my `HousesController new action`

```
def new
 @house = House.find(params[:id])
 @house.house_rules.build
end
```

Comment: Could you try using just `<%= house_rule.check_box :allowed %> `?
If that does not help, try to debug from within controller to see if there is anything passed in params.

Comment: Hello @Diodon, I want the checked value of the check box to be 'yes' and unchecked value to be 'no'. That's why I gave it like that.

Comment: Yea, you are right. Sorry. Could you tell exactly what does not work and show the action of HousesController.

Comment: Have you compared your code to the _task & _subtask in the demo project?  (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/tree/master/app/views/projects)  ... deploying that helped me out when testing from a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not render the form correctly, since you are not actually iterating over nested rows, that is why the id is 0 for all rows.

Instead I would precreate all predefined rules for a `house` in your controller, in the `new` action. As follows:

```rb
def new 
  @house = House.new 
  HouseRule.predefined.each do |hr|
    @house.house_rules.build(rule: hr.rule)
  end 
end
```

And in your view just iterate over the house-rules as usual:

```rb
<%=  f.simple_fields_for :house_rules do |house_rule| %>
  <%= house_rule.label :allowed, house_rule.object.rule %>
  <%= house_rule.check_box :allowed, {}, 'yes', 'no' %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks @nathanvda, its working fine now. Thank you for your time.