# Update multiple checkboxes on association model through nested attributes with Cocoon gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034905/update-multiple-checkboxes-on-association-model-through-nested-attributes-coco) which should be able to solve my problem but turns out that answer is for a one to many association. Btw, i'm using Rails 5.2

In my many to many, I have a Task model which has_many `test_methods` through `tasks_test_methods` where `tasks_test_methods` is a join table.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks_test_methods, inverse_of: :task, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :test_methods, :through => :tasks_test_methods

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks_test_methods, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is my join table model `tasks_test_methods`

```
class TasksTestMethod < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :test_method

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :test_method, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

And my TestMethod model

```
class TestMethod < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks_test_methods, inverse_of: :test_method, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :tasks, :through => :tasks_test_methods
end
```

My TasksTestMethods table is simple and only receives the `task_id` and `test_method_id`

```
create_table "tasks_test_methods", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "task_id", null: false
    t.bigint "test_method_id", null: false
end
```

I have a list of predefined `test_methods` that are displayed and needs to be added to a `task` upon creation. For example.

```
<TestMethod id: 1, name: "Visual Testing (VT)", code: nil, description: nil, category_id: 1, created_at: "2018-05-15 12:11:38", updated_at: "2018-05-15 12:11:38">
```

I want to have all these `test_methods` in the new `task` form like this
[image]

So when users checks a checkbox with label `Visual Testing` a new record is created like this (an example from the rails console):

```
2.5.1 :176 > params = { task: { name: "Test", client_id: 1, tasks_test_methods_attributes: [test_method_id: 1]}}
 => {:task=>{:name=>"Test", :client_id=>1, :tasks_test_methods_attributes=>[{:test_method_id=>1}]}}
2.5.1 :177 > task = Task.create!(params[:task])
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<TasksTestMethod task_id: 16, test_method_id: 2>]>
```

This is my new `task` form, here I'm using cocoon gem already in the `fields_for` part

```
= form_with(model: @task) do |f|
  .form-group
     %label Client Name:
        = f.select(:client_id, @clients.collect { |client| [ client.name, client.id ] }, { include_blank: "Select Client" }, { :class => 'form-control select2', style: 'width: 100%;' })
   .col-md-12
      = f.fields_for :tasks_test_method do |task_test_method|
        = render 'test_method_fields', f: task_test_method
```

And in the `test_method_fields` partial I have this:

```
= collection_check_boxes :tasks_test_method, :test_method_ids, @test_methods, :id, :name do |box| 
  .form-group.row 
    .form-check.col-md-3
      = box.check_box
      %span.ml-2 
        = box.label
```

The above code shows the checkboxes as expected, but doesn't work as expected. Can someone guide me on how to make this work?

I have also whitelisted these in the `TasksController`

```
tasks_test_methods_attributes: [:id, test_method_ids: []])
```

This is the code form produces for each checkbox in the browser console

```
<div class="form-check col-md-3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="tasks_test_method[test_method_ids][]" id="tasks_test_method_test_method_ids_1">
  <span class="ml-2">
   <label for="tasks_test_method_test_method_ids_1">Visual Testing (VT)</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is I can't get the `tasks_test_methods_attributes` into the params, also when I click on 2 of the `test_methods` and try to add a task, for example, I get this in the console:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cuEnQNeh4iT+38AwsNduQGce5kxFcS7sFw0SAgpdvxJjVziFTnrSgzdq6LODNDxzhan2ne31YMeCcJdYL8VoSQ==", "task"=>{"client_id"=>"", "name"=>"", "department_id"=>"", "start_date"=>"", "offshore_flag"=>"0", "order_number"=>"", "description"=>"", "task_manager_id"=>"", "language_id"=>"", "client_ref"=>"", "testsite"=>"", "contact_person_phone"=>"", "contact_person"=>"", "contact_person_email"=>"", "information_to_operator"=>""}, "tasks_test_method"=>{"test_method_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
```

When I try to create a `Task`, it's been created but without the `tasks_test_methods_attributes` part in the params.

This is my `TasksController new action`

```
def new
  @task = Task.new 
  TestMethod.all.each do |test_method|
    @task.tasks_test_methods.build(test_method_id: test_method.id)
  end
 end
```

Comment: can you help me in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74517496/how-to-update-multiple-checkboxes-values-on-join-table-through-nested-attributes
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got an answer for this task. My whole approach was wrong, trying to insert directly into a join table (That's never going to work!).

[This article](https://learn.co/lessons/has-many-through-forms-rails) helped me figure out my mistake, after reading it multiple times. Ended up fixing the problem in 3 mins, after taking about 3 days to search for a solution.

In your model, accept nested attributes for the join table like so:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks_test_methods, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

While reading the [cocoon gem documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), I found this statement that makes sense. 
`When saving nested items, theoretically the parent is not yet saved on validation, so rails needs help to know the link between relations. There are two ways: either declare the belongs_to as optional: false, but the cleanest way is to specify the inverse_of: on the has_many. That is why we write : has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :test_method`

Now in my `Task` model, I have

```
has_many :tasks_test_methods, inverse_of: :task, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :test_methods, :through => :tasks_test_methods
```

Also in my `TestMethod` model, I have

```
has_many :tasks_test_methods, inverse_of: :test_method, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :tasks, :through => :tasks_test_methods
```

And then in the `TasksController` I added this to the params, `test_method_ids: []`

And finally in the form I have this:

```
.form-group
   = f.collection_check_boxes :test_method_ids, @test_methods, :id, :name do |test_method|
      .form-check.mb-4
         = test_method.check_box(class: "form-check-input")
         %label.form-check-label 
            %span.ml-2  
              = test_method.label
```

And when now your HTML element should look like this:

```
<div class="form-check mb-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="task[test_method_ids][]" id="task_test_method_ids_1">
  <label class="form-check-label">
   <span class="ml-2">
     <label for="task_test_method_ids_1">Visual Testing (VT)</label>
   </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.