# How to update multiple checkboxes values on join table through nested attributes with Cocoon gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, cocoon-gem, fields-for

I did some research and found this([Update multiple checkboxes on association model through nested attributes with Cocoon gem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397979/update-multiple-checkboxes-on-association-model-through-nested-attributes-with-c)) but my case is a bit different i assume.

Suppose I have 3 models: User, Client, Role. The relation is many_to_many through assignments between User & Client and same many_to_many through assignments between User and Role.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, inverse_of: :user, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, inverse_of: :client, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, inverse_of: :role, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

Join table Assignment

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Assignment table contains user_id, role_id, client_id

My views:

**form.html.erb**

```
      <%= f.fields_for :assignments,url: url do |assignment_form| %>
        
          <%= render partial: 'users/assignment_fields', locals: { f: assignment_form,user: @user } %>
       

      <% end %>
      <div>
        <%= link_to_add_association "Add", f, :assignments, partial: 'users/assignment_fields',render_options: { locals:{ user: @user } } %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**_assignment_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :role_id, Role.all, :id, :short_name, html_options = {} %>
```

params permit:

```
[:first_name, :last_name,assignments_attributes: [:client_id, role_id: [] ] ]
```

params in console.

```
 "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"d",  "assignments_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"client_id"=>"2", "role_id"=>["2", "4"], "id"=>"300"}
```

Now what i need to do is save the User form along with the fields shown below in the link screenshot. The below shown fields needs to be saved in the Assignments join table.Note: I am using cocoon to add more records.

I want know how can I save the role_ids that come to the Assignment which means if we have 2 roles for a client then 2 different records needs to be created in the join assignment table.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAvfe.png  [Screenshot link]

Comment: What is currently not working?  What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: Actually the form is getting submitted but without saving the roles [1,2,3] for a client in assignment table. So I want to save the roles through user form for which I have used fields_for in assignment table. So the data should be saved like user_id,role_id,client_id => {1,1,1},{1,2,1},{1,3,1} in assignment join table.